# Automapper - why use Mapper.Initialize?

Tags: c#, automapper

I wouldn't normally ask this kind of question on here, but unfortunately whilst [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) seems to be a good mapping library, its documentation is woefully bad - there is no XML documentation for the library's methods, and the most official online documentation I could find was [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki), which is very brisk.  If anyone has any better documentation, please let me know.

That said, here's the question: why use `Mapper.Initialize`?  It doesn't seem to be required as you can just use `Mapper.CreateMap` immediately, and as there is no documentation I have no clue what `Initialize` is meant to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I asked on the AutoMapper users list, and this answer basically says why:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/automapper-users/0RgIjrKi28U

It's something to do with allowing AutoMapper to do deterministic (stochastic) optimization.  Performance-wise, it's better to get all your mappings created in the `Initialize` call.

Answer (score 7):

The initialization runs all the map creation once so it is then done when you come to do your mapping. You can create a map whenever you want, but this will slow your code down as the mapping creation involves reflection.

I find it best to use profiles for my mapping code and use something like the following to get this all setup:

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration : IRequiresConfigurationOnStartUp
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public AutoMapperConfiguration(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x => GetAutoMapperConfiguration(Mapper.Configuration));
    }

    private void GetAutoMapperConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var profiles = GetProfiles();
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            configuration.AddProfile(_container.GetInstance(profile) as Profile);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetProfiles()
    {
        return typeof(AutoMapperConfiguration).Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => !type.IsAbstract && typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(type));
    }
}
```

Comment: And where do you run `Configure` from in an MVC application?

Comment: @Jez, I assume that IRequiresConfigurationOnStartUp requires a Configure method and that this will ensure that Configure is called. However, Microsoft does not document this interface. Where does this come from? There is an interface in Google Code, see http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/source/browse/trunk/src/DependencyResolution/IRequiresConfigurationOnStartup.cs?r=1021

Comment: IRequiresConfigurationOnStartUp is an interface I created, I use StructureMap to scan for instances and run the Configure method

Comment: AutoMapper has some built in functionality to add profiles nowadays: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration.